# I know R^4 and C are non-isomorphic vector spaces, but how do I prove it?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that if I am to claim that R^4 and C are isomoprhic I will have to find an f that is one-to-one. That means that it will have to take every quad of R^4 and match it to an R^2 dyad, say (a,b) where z=a+bi, zεC and a,bεC. That's not possible, but how can I prove it?

Comment: Isomorphic spaces have the same dimension.

Comment: Yes but how can I prove that? Even more, when i've read somewhere that vector spaces above Q are isomorphic.

Comment: @JPLF aren't they: $\dim_{\boldsymbol{C}}(\boldsymbol{R}^4)=2=\dim_{\boldsymbol{R}}(\boldsymbol{C})$.  Just nitpicking.

Comment: A vector space $V$ over $\mathbb R$ has dimension $n$ iff $V \cong \mathbb R^n$. So $\mathbb R^4$ has dimension $4$, while $\mathbb C$ has dimension $2$.

Answer (score 1):

You must find a homomorphism from $\Bbb R^4\to \Bbb C$ which is isomorphism,not just a $f$ which is one-to-one.

Now if you consider $\Bbb C$ to be a vector space over $\Bbb R$ then $\Bbb C$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$.

Isomorphism is a equivalence relation and thus we must have that $\Bbb R^2=\Bbb R^4$ as isomorphism (=).

But $\Bbb R^2$ is a 2-dimentional vector space over $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^4$ is a 4-dimentional vector space over $\Bbb R$. Thus they are not isomorphic.

Comment: Κι εγώ εκανα ακριβώς αυτην την σκέψη, απλά δεν γνωρίζω αν μπορώ να δουλέψω με τέτοιου είδους ισοδυναμίες. Ιδιαίτερα καθώς διάβασα πως οι χώροι ανω του Q είναι ισομορφικοί.

Comment: @PanagiotisFilianos,correct. That's why though i wrote 'vector space over $\Bbb R$:). Also write in english in order to everyone understand what we say:). And welcome to the forum fellow countryman:)

Comment: /Translated above; I've had the exact same thought I just didn't know if I was able to use such kind of equivalence relations on vector spaces. Especially when i read that vector spaces above Q are isomorphic.